# Do we expect similar results in form of measurement histogram for both (1 run with 100 shots) and (100 runs with 1 shot each)?

Tags: noise

100 runs of 1 shot each were executed one by one over a single qubit initialised with 0 (default) and no quantum gate implemented on top of it. All measurement results were found to be noise free i.e. 100% of measurements yielded 0.
However, runs with 100 shots rarely yield 100% accuracy.

Comment: what is the context? In an ideal scenario, there is no difference between the two cases. If you refer to a specific experimental scenario or model, you should clarify which one